# class attribute considered abstract method in python 2.7 - abc module

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, abc

I am trying to implement an abstract superclass (Base) with an abstract method (addfeature), which the Child class will override.

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    ns = "http://www.foo.com/bar"
    em = ElementMaker(namespace=ns, nsmap={'bar': ns})

    @abstractmethod
    def addfeature(self):
        pass

class Child(Base):
    def addfeature(self):
        pass

child_instance = Child()
```

This code fails however with

> "TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Child with abstract
>   methods em"

Why? em is supposed to be a class attribute, not a method (and surely not an abstract method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ABCMeta` check whether the method is abstract or not by using `__isabstractmethod__` attribute. The `lxml.builder.ElementMaker` dynamically generate a method (using [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)); access to `__isabstractmethod__` confuse the `ABCMeta`.

```
>>> ns = "http://www.foo.com/bar"
>>> em = ElementMaker(namespace=ns, nsmap={'bar': ns})
>>> em.child_element
<functools.partial object at 0x0000000002B55598>
>>> em.child_element()
<Element {http://www.foo.com/bar}child_element at 0x27a8828>
>>> em.__isabstractmethod__
<functools.partial object at 0x0000000002B55598>
>>> bool(em.__isabstractmethod__)
True
```

By assigning `__isabstractmethod__` as a `False`, you can work around it.

```
class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    ns = "http://www.foo.com/bar"
    em = ElementMaker(namespace=ns, nsmap={'bar': ns})
    em.__isabstractmethod__ = False  # <-----

    @abstractmethod
    def addfeature(self):
        pass
```